# JSF2: Remove cookie from request that gets redirected with faces-redirect=true

Tags: cookies, jsf-2, request, java-ee-6

I have the following problem: 
A method `deleteCookie` in one of my CDI beans is responsible for removing cookies. Currently I do:

```
deleteCookie() {
    Map<String, Object> cookieProperties = new HashMap<>();
    cookieProperties.put("maxAge", new Integer(0));
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().addResponseCookie(COOKIE_NAME, "", cookieProperties);
}
```

These cookies are used by a `ServletFilter (implementing javax.servlet.Filter)` and I expect them not to be there anymore after calling `deleteCookie()`.

When this method is triggered by a command button this only works, when I it does NOT return a faces-redirect=true. E.g. `/index` works, but `/index/faces-redirect=true` does not work.

The reason is, that `faces-redirect=true` causes the Filter to be applied again to the redirected request that still has the cookies. The cookies are only removed, after a response is send to the client.

How can I remove the cookies from the request that is sent with the redirect?

best wishes
Shizanu

Comment: Are you sure you use `/index/faces-redirect=true`? It should be `index?faces-redirect=true`.

Comment: Have you solved this?